# C# Using Regular Expressions

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

The following works in vb.net, and basically only allows characters on a standard US Keyboard. Any other character pasted gets deleted. I use the following regular expression code:

```
"[^A-Za-z0-9\[\{\}\]`~!@#$%\^&*\(\)_\-+=\\/:;'""<>,\.|? ]", "")
```

However when I try to use it in C# it won't work, I used '\' as a escape sequence. C# seems a bit different when it comes to escape sequences? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show the code you are using, both in VB.NET and in C#.

Answer (score 3):

Prefix the string with `@`. That's it. From there you can use the regex string from VB as is (including doubling up on the `"` character).

```
// Note: exact same string you're using, only with a @ verbatim prefix.
string regex = @"[^A-Za-z0-9\[\{\}\]`~!@#$%\^&*\(\)_\-+=\\/:;'""<>,\.|? ]";
string crazy = "hĀečlĤlŁoźtƢhǣeǮrȡe";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(crazy, regex, ""));
```

Output:

```
hellothere
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefix your string with "@" and prefix quotes within the string with "\".

I.e. this string

> abc\def"hij

in C# would be encoded as

```
@"abc\def\"hij"
```

Comment: Using the @ prefix, it should be @"bc\def""hij", \ isn't an escape character.

Comment: @Rob is right: in a verbatim string literal you escape a double-quote with another double-quote, not with a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your " character. Do this by putting a \ before your " character.

```
"[^A-Za-z0-9[{}]`~!@#$%\^&*()_-+=\/:;'""<>,.|? ]"
```

should become

```
"[^A-Za-z0-9[{}]`~!@#$%\^&*()_-+=\/:;'\"\"<>,.|? ]"
```

If you use the @prefix before this,  it will treat the backslash literally instead of an escape character and you wont get the desired result.

Comment: Actually, if he sticks a `@` onto the string literal, the regex should work as it is.  Specifically, the double-quote is already escaped with another double-quote.

Answer (score 0):

Escape your characters:

```
"[^A-Za-z0-9[{}]`~!@#$%\^&*()_-+=\\/:;'\"<>,.|? ]"
```

A good tool for regular expression design and testing (free) is:
http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/

Comment: Your first regex won't work because it contains an unescaped double-quote.  You need to escape it with another double-quote (`""`).

Answer (score 0):

You need  to escape you regex for use in C#

```
[^A-Za-z0-9\[\{\}\]`~!@#$%\^&*\(\)_\-+=\\/:;'\"<>,\.|? ]
```

Try this one!